# How to write my SQL to filter by user without losing rows?

Tags: mysql

I have this SQL to fetch a calendar with info about dates.

```
SELECT h.user_id, name, description, name_day, h.holiday_id, day 
FROM calendar_dates d left join calendar_date_holiday h on d.id=h.date_id 
left join calendar_holidays hs on h.holiday_id=hs.id 
WHERE h.user_id IS NULL 
or h.user_id IN (SELECT id FROM calendar_users WHERE username='bd107a66ba') 
order by day asc
```

That works if another user doesn't have a holiday_id for a holiday. Now I'd like to also join holiday ids that have other user_id:s than the condition (´ WHERE h.user_id IS NULL or h.user_id IN ( SELECT id FROM calendar_users WHERE username='bd107a66ba')`) but I don't want the holidays for other users. How can I achieve it?

For example if no user has any own holiday then the result is good

```
  user_id name description name_day holiday_id day
    NULL    NULL   NULL      Name     NULL      1
...

    (30 rows)
```

If another user than `bd107a66ba` insert a holiday, then I get only 29 rows since that is not joined. should I use a union? I want a blank holiday if some other user has a holiday on the same day and not the current user.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results to better explain what you are really trying to do?

Comment: Possibly put the WHERE clause into the ON clause for the first join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you might be best adding an extra join to the calendar users table (probably an INNER JOIN as I assume the username you are checking must exist on that), then use the user id from that in the join against calendar_date_holiday:-

```
SELECT h.user_id, name, description, name_day, h.holiday_id, day 
FROM calendar_dates d 
INNER JOIN calendar_users cu
ON cu.username = 'bd107a66ba'
LEFT JOIN calendar_date_holiday h 
ON d.id = h.date_id 
AND h.user_id = cu.id 
LEFT JOIN calendar_holidays hs 
ON h.holiday_id = hs.id 
ORDER BY day ASC
```